# tf.keras - Importing model with batchnormalization layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I've gotten stuck on this issue for a little while. I'm trying to run the code below with the tf_cnnvis (https://github.com/InFoCusp/tf_cnnvis) package for visualising learnt features in the network, where I import my protobuf model and then try and provide it a tensor containing some image data (which I believe is provided as a feed_dict, although I could be mistaken).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as k
import cv2
import tf_cnnvis as tfv
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

from keras import backend as K

model_filename = "saved_model.pb"
image = "test.jpg"

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.8, allow_growth=False)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

K.set_session(sess)
K._LEARNING_PHASE = tf.constant(0)
K.set_learning_phase(0)

with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 48, 64, 3],name = "input") # placeholder for input images
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 8])
im = np.array(cv2.imread(image))
im = np.expand_dims(im, 0)

layers = ['r', 'p', 'c']

init_op = init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)

with sess.as_default():
    is_success = tfv.activation_visualization(sess_graph_path=tf.get_default_graph(), value_feed_dict = {X : im}, layers=layers)

sess.close()
```

When I run my code, I get an "InvalidArgumentError" with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1292, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1277, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1367, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'import/batch_normalization_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,48,64,3]
     [[{{node import/batch_normalization_1_input}} = Placeholder[_class=["loc:@import/batch_normalization/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,48,64,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node import/conv2d/Relu/_5}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_50_import/conv2d/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis2.py", line 36, in <module>
    is_success = tfv.activation_visualization(sess_graph_path=tf.get_default_graph(), value_feed_dict = {X : im}, layers=layers)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 406, in activation_visualization
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 169, in _get_visualization
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 227, in _visualization_by_layer_type
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 288, in _visualization_by_layer_name
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 315, in _activation
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 887, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1110, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1286, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1308, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'import/batch_normalization_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,48,64,3]
     [[{{node import/batch_normalization_1_input}} = Placeholder[_class=["loc:@import/batch_normalization/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,48,64,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node import/conv2d/Relu/_5}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_50_import/conv2d/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'import/batch_normalization_1_input', defined at:
  File "vis2.py", line 36, in <module>
    is_success = tfv.activation_visualization(sess_graph_path=tf.get_default_graph(), value_feed_dict = {X : im}, layers=layers)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 406, in activation_visualization
    path_logdir = path_logdir, path_outdir = path_outdir)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 159, in _get_visualization
    s = _graph_import_function(PATH,s)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 177, in _graph_import_function
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(PATH) # Import graph
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1650, in import_meta_graph
    meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, **kwargs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1672, in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 806, in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    return_elements=return_elements)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 442, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 234, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3285, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'import/batch_normalization_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,48,64,3]
     [[{{node import/batch_normalization_1_input}} = Placeholder[_class=["loc:@import/batch_normalization/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1/Switch"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,48,64,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[{{node import/conv2d/Relu/_5}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_50_import/conv2d/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Now, I've looked around and I've arrived (tentatively) at the conclusion that this is due to a learning phase variable that's set in the BatchNormalization layer that I have in the model. I'm unclear as to how to set the learning phase when you've imported the model. Some people set the learning phase before initializing the model (which as you can see, I have attempted), but in most examples of this they're using one of the large, pre-provided models (such as MNIST). Others provide the learning phase in the feed_dict, which I have also tried, like so:

```
with sess.as_default():
    is_success = tfv.activation_visualization(sess_graph_path=tf.get_default_graph(), value_feed_dict = {X : im, K.learning_phase(): 0}, layers=layers)
```

But this gives me a different error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis2.py", line 36, in <module>
    is_success = tfv.activation_visualization(sess_graph_path=tf.get_default_graph(), value_feed_dict = {X : im, K.learning_phase(): 0}, layers=layers)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 406, in activation_visualization
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 169, in _get_visualization
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 227, in _visualization_by_layer_type
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/tf_cnnvis.py", line 270, in _visualization_by_layer_name
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tf_cnnvis-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/tf_cnnvis/utils.py", line 79, in parse_tensors_dict
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

At this stage, seeing as I'm still not completely sure if the problem I'm trying to fix is even the right one, I would very much appreciate some input. If there's anything else you need me to provide, please ask.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  I'm trying to visualize a keras CNN with tf_cnnvis